# WebSphere configuration file storage

Tags: websphere, properties-file

I'm looking for information on where the JVM custom properties are stored and how they are protected.  Are they encoded, encrypted, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In case of traditional WebSphere Application Server they are stored in the `server.xml` file in the following location (by default) `/install_root/profiles/<profile_name>/config/cells/<cellname>/nodes/<nodename>/servers/server1/server.xml`

In case of WebSphere Liberty or Open Liberty they are stored in `jvm.options` file in the server directory `/wlp/usr/servers/<servername>`

In both cases they are in plain text.

Why would you like to encode/encrypt them?

If you want to store for example database credentials, then you should create datasource and authentication alias. Password in authentication alias can be encoded (xor) or encrypted (aes).

Or use system environment variables to pass them during the runtime and not store in the configuration. You can pass environment variables to docker containers via `-e` or in Kubernetes via Secrets/ConfigMaps.